# Change ID length and cleaner datatype

Tags: json, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, data-annotations

well I'm doing a project where my JSON file has to give me for example this response in that format:

```json
"activityId" : 1
"startDate" : "2023-02-12 04:00:00",
"endDate" : "2023-03-22 12:00:00",
```

Is there any way to get to that format using dataannotations or without using SQL? (I have no problem deleting my migration and start it again cause is a vey small project) thanks

mM class is build like this and I made the migration with EF:

```cs
[Key]
public Guid activityId { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
public DateTime startDate { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
```

and what I got is this:

```json
"activityId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f78afa6",
"startDate": "2023-02-14T18:11:21.463Z",
"endDate": "2023-02-14T18:11:21.463Z",
```

Comment: Is your question how to format datetime strings in the json outputfile?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: yes, format datetime strings and the ID start from 1